# emacs on windows hangs when running rgrep

Tags: rgrep, find

I am running emacs 27.2 on Windows 10.

When I execute the rgrep function, after inserting my choices for REGEXP, FILES and DIR, it hangs.

I have set the variable debug-on-entry and here's what I get:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (quit)
  call-process("find" nil nil nil "NUL" "-ls")
  apply(call-process "find" nil nil nil ("NUL" "-ls"))
  process-file("find" nil nil nil "NUL" "-ls")
  #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x7e7e8290fd>)()
  funcall(#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x7e7e8290fd>))
  eval((funcall #'#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x7e7e8290fd>)))
  custom-initialize-reset(find-ls-option (funcall #'#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x7e7e8290fd>)))
  custom-declare-variable(find-ls-option (funcall #'#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x7e7e8290fd>)) "A pair of options to produce and parse an `ls -l'-..." :version "27.1" :type (choice (cons :tag "find -ls" (string "-ls") (string "-dilsb")) (cons :tag "find -exec ls -ld" (string "-exec ls -ld {} +") (string "-ld")) (cons :tag "find -print | sort | xargs" (string "-print0 | sort -z | xargs -0 -e ls -ld") (string "-ld")) (cons :tag "Other values" (string :tag "Find Option") (string :tag "Ls Switches"))) :group find-dired)
  byte-code("\303\304\305\306\307DD\310\311\312\313\314\315\316\317\320\10@D\320\10AD\257\5\315\316\321\320\11@D\320\11AD\257\5\315\316\322\320\n@D\320\nAD\257..." [find-ls-option-default-ls find-ls-option-default-exec find-ls-option-default-xargs custom-declare-variable find-ls-option funcall function #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x7e7e8290fd>) "A pair of options to produce and parse an `ls -l'-..." :version "27.1" :type choice cons :tag "find -ls" string "find -exec ls -ld" "find -print | sort | xargs" ((cons :tag "Other values" (string :tag "Find Option") (string :tag "Ls Switches"))) :group find-dired find-ls-subdir-switches #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x7e7e83b00d>) "`ls' switches for inserting subdirectories in `*Fi..." "24.1" find-grep-options #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x7e7e83e03d>) "Option to grep to be as silent as possible.\nOn Ber..." find-name-arg #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x7e7e83e3d9>) "Argument used to specify file name pattern.\nIf `re..." "22.2" find-dired-refine-function #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x7e7e402999>) "If non-nil, a function for refining the *Find* buf..." (choice (const :tag "Sort file names lexicographically" find-dired-sort-by-filename) (function :tag "Refining function") (const :tag "No refining" nil))] 16)
  require(find-dired)
  rgrep-default-command("COEX" "*.[ch]" nil)
  rgrep("COEX" "*.[ch]" "~/Workspace/dev/FW/FW/FW/" nil)
  funcall-interactively(rgrep "COEX" "*.[ch]" "~/Workspace/dev/FW/FW/FW/" nil)
  call-interactively(rgrep nil nil)
  command-execute(rgrep)
```

REGEX being "COEX", FILES being "*.[ch]" and "~/Workspace/dev/FW/FW/FW/" being DIR.

Under the hood, I am using some GnuWin32 utilities, including find and grep.

Here's the backtrace for `M-x load-library RET find-dired.el RET` with debug-on-quit set

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (quit)
  call-process("find" nil nil nil "NUL" "-ls")
  apply(call-process "find" nil nil nil ("NUL" "-ls"))
  process-file("find" nil nil nil "NUL" "-ls")
  (progn (process-file find-program nil nil nil null-device "-ls"))
  (condition-case nil (progn (process-file find-program nil nil nil null-device "-ls")) (error nil))
  (eq 0 (condition-case nil (progn (process-file find-program nil nil nil null-device "-ls")) (error nil)))
  (if (eq 0 (condition-case nil (progn (process-file find-program nil nil nil null-device "-ls")) (error nil))) find-ls-option-default-ls find-ls-option-default-exec)
  (closure (t) nil (if (eq 0 (condition-case nil (progn (process-file find-program nil nil nil null-device "-ls")) (error nil))) find-ls-option-default-ls find-ls-option-default-exec))()
  funcall((closure (t) nil (if (eq 0 (condition-case nil (progn (process-file find-program nil nil nil null-device "-ls")) (error nil))) find-ls-option-default-ls find-ls-option-default-exec)))
  eval((funcall #'(closure (t) nil (if (eq 0 (condition-case nil (progn ...) (error nil))) find-ls-option-default-ls find-ls-option-default-exec))))
  custom-initialize-reset(find-ls-option (funcall #'(closure (t) nil (if (eq 0 (condition-case nil (progn ...) (error nil))) find-ls-option-default-ls find-ls-option-default-exec))))
  custom-declare-variable(find-ls-option (funcall #'(closure (t) nil (if (eq 0 (condition-case nil (progn ...) (error nil))) find-ls-option-default-ls find-ls-option-default-exec))) "A pair of options to produce and parse an `ls -l'-..." :version "27.1" :type (choice (cons :tag "find -ls" (string "-ls") (string "-dilsb")) (cons :tag "find -exec ls -ld" (string "-exec ls -ld {} +") (string "-ld")) (cons :tag "find -print | sort | xargs" (string "-print0 | sort -z | xargs -0 -e ls -ld") (string "-ld")) (cons :tag "Other values" (string :tag "Find Option") (string :tag "Ls Switches"))) :group find-dired)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "c:/Program Files/emacs-27.2/share/emacs/27.2/lisp/find-dired.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 3906
  load-with-code-conversion("c:/Program Files/emacs-27.2/share/emacs/27.2/lisp/find-dired.el" "c:/Program Files/emacs-27.2/share/emacs/27.2/lisp/..." nil nil)
  load("find-dired.el")
  load-library("find-dired.el")
  funcall-interactively(load-library "find-dired.el")
  call-interactively(load-library record nil)
  command-execute(load-library record)
  execute-extended-command(nil "load-library" "load-li")
  funcall-interactively(execute-extended-command nil "load-library" "load-li")
  call-interactively(execute-extended-command nil nil)
  command-execute(execute-extended-command)
```

Not sure where things are going wrong. Can anyone help?

Comment: Between the `rgrep` call and the `process-file` call, things have gone wonky. I would (naively - haven't really checked)  have expected the `call-process` line to look something like this: `call-process("find" nil <some-buffer> "/path/to/Workspace/dev/FW/FW/FW" "*.el" "-ls")`. Have you tried with `emacs -q` thereby bypassing your init file? Maybe you are doing something in the init file to cause the wonkiness.

Comment: I get the same output from the debugger with runemacs -q

Comment: Also find-grep works, even if I edit the command to be what it should be with rgrep, that is `find . -type f -name "*.[ch]" -exec grep --color=always -nH --null -e COEX "{}"`

Comment: Is the `find` command that it's picking up the **MS Windows** `find` command, perhaps? That's a common problem. (I didn't look at your question closely - just mentioning this in case it's relevant.)

Comment: I suggest you `M-x load-library RET find-dired.el RET` and then see if you get a more detailed backtrace.

Comment: I have added the backtrace in the post as output is too long for comment

Comment: That is the proper place for it even if it was short: you should never add vital information in comments, only in the question. The question should stand on its own, even if all the comments are deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `find . -ls` (using GnuWin32 find version 4.2.20) hangs. I workaround that issue by using ezwinports find.